# How does the compiler find the implicit method for Json.obj()?

Tags: scala, playframework, play-json

We could build a json object just like this:

```
import java.time.Instant
import play.api.libs.json.Json

object Test extends App {
  println(Json.obj("time" -> Instant.now()))
  //Output: {"time":"2018-05-25T18:13:23.409Z"}
}
```

The signature of Json.obj() method is:

```
def obj(fields: (String, JsValueWrapper)*): JsObject
```

While the implicit method `Json.toJsFieldJsValueWrapper` is not in scope, how is `Instant.now()` converted to `JsValueWrapper` successfully ? Thanks in advance for your reply !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the answer from here [Outer Objects for Nested Types](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html). The reason is that the outer objects for nested types also contribute implicits.